# Compilation error with C++ templates

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile a [program](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/dad6c31e-2c04-471f-b724-ded18bf70fe3/) developed in 2006.  Unfortunately, it does not compile any longer.

Here is a minimal example of the problem:

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "file1.h"
int main() {
    A<B> c;
}
```

`file1.h`:

```
#ifndef _file1_H_
#define _file1_H_
#include "file2.h"
template <class T> class A {
    int a;
    A ();
};
#endif
```

`file1.cpp`:

```
#include "file1.h"
#include "file.inc"
template <class T> A<T>::A(): a(0) { }
```

`file2.h`:

```
template <class T> class A;
class B {
    int b;
};
```

`file.inc`:

```
#include "file1.h"
template A<B>;
```

I omit the (straightforward) Makefile.  The compiler says:

```
file.inc:2:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘;’ token
  template A<B>;
               ^
```

I have tried g++-4.7  g++-4.8  g++-4.9  g++-5 and g++-5.2 (on Ubuntu), with no luck.  The author says that it compiles with GNU c++ compiler version 2.96.  I would like to somehow fix the code so that it works on my machine with at least one of the g++ versions (preferably 5.2).

---

**ANSWER**:
As mentionned (instantaneously) by the community, `file.inc` should be:

```
template class A<B>;
```

I still need to brush up my skills in C++!

Comment: `template class A<B>;`.

Comment: To find more, search for "explicit template instantiation".

Comment: And those reserved names need to die a fiery death.

Comment: Finally, `"file.inc"` is included too early to do much good there. It needs to be included *after* `A`'s member function definitions, not before.

Comment: Are you asking how to modify the program such that it compiles with a modern compiler or what compiler settings to use in a modern compiler such that it accepts the old code?

Comment: Identifiers like `__file1_H__` are reserved to the implementation.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I just want to compile the code on my PC.  I am OK to modify it (without changing the algorithms, obviously).

Comment: @unamourdeswann: You should explicitly mention that in your question, I think. And if you say "on my PC", then that's too vague. Do you know which compiler you want to use? Which operating system? Are you OK with downloading a new compiler or is there one particular version you have to use?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I did not know that.  The author gave more realistic names.

Comment: What makes the names reserved is the double underscores.  They are *almost* certainly not your problem, but you should get rid of them if they are there (and remove them from your example).

Comment: @MartinBonner: Ok! But that was in the original code.